# Keeps crashing on 3rd if condition

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement

So I am kind of new to programming (16 y/o) and I have been solving problems for a while now, but now I am solving this one prob (which is quite easy) there seems to be just one thing getting on my way. The problem is pretty simple, it only needs me to read 3 integers and print out the greatest one, I have already solved it in C++/C and had no problem, at all. But this one, It prints out and works perfectly when the first two if conditions are true (if a is the greatest value, it prints a, if b is the greatest value it prints b) but when c is the greatest value it comes out empty. Sorry for the long post, hope someone can help me out.

```
 using System;
```

namespace MaxP351
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            string[] input = Console.ReadLine ().Split (' '); // getting input as string
            int[] nums = new int[input.Length]; // declaring int array with same length as input
            for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++) { // starting a for loop to convert input string to int in nums[]
                nums[i] = Convert.ToInt32(input[i]);
            }
            int a, b, c;
            a = nums [0];
            b = nums [1];
            c = nums [2];
            if (a > b && a > c) {
                Console.WriteLine (a);
                break;
            } else if (b > a && b > c) {
                Console.WriteLine (b);
                break;
            } else if (c > a && c > b) {
                Console.WriteLine (c);
                break;
            }

`}
}`

Comment: What the exception is?

Comment: Can you surround your code with `try{} catch()`?

Comment: Why you are using `break;`?

Comment: With or without <pre>break;<code> it is the same, I was just messing around with the code to see if anything happens or if I am missing out on anything

Comment: Your input way is wrong.

Comment: In your program user can be put 1, 2 or many numbers with `space` but your are handling only three numbers `a`, `b` and `c`

Answer (score 2):

If `c` is truly the largest number then your code should be printing out the value for `c`.  If this were my code, I would set a break point at your `if` statement and see what the values are.  Alternatively you can print out the values of a,b and c right before your if statements and make sure they are the values that you expect.  Example:

```
Console.WriteLine("Values before if statement:")
Console.WriteLine (a);
Console.WriteLine (b);
Console.WriteLine (c);
if (a > b && a > c) {
...
```

Again - I would recommend going the breakpoint route, but the above might be a quick and dirty way to see the values if you aren't familiar with visual studio debugging.

In summary - your code should give you the desired output.  The problem most likely lies somewhere else.

Comment: Regardless of the value it's always c failing if it is the greatest, the input in the problem was 87 3 438 here: http://i.imgur.com/yrEGIES.png
I am not using Visual Studio, I am using Xamarin Studio because I can't solve problems in Visual Studio for some reason and the online judge requires C# (gmcs 2.0.1) for some reason.

Comment: @Eyad - did you try printing out like I mentioned?

Answer (score 2):

**1.** No need break; for if-else statements.

**2.** No need if statements at all to display the largest integer. You can do below.

```
 Console.WriteLine(nums.Max())
```

**3.** If you don't want to use Max function. Do a proper loop which is better than too many if conditions;

```
    int? maxVal = null; // ? means nullable int. Set null just to initialize

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
    {
      int currentNum = nums[i];
      if (!maxVal.HasValue || currentNum > maxVal.Value)
      {
        maxVal = currentNum;
      }
    }

   Console.WriteLine(maxVal);
```

Comment: I can't use .Max() for some reason, I am writing C# in Xamarin studio not in Visual studio because I am solving problems.

Comment: @Eyad: May be something is wrong with ReadLine or Split ? Make sure you enter values properly. Can you put a break point and debug the value in c?

Comment: I did try to compile the same code with Visual Studio since it gives better info on where the prob actually is than Xamarin and it said something about split(); not working on more than two integers, even though it obviously does and it's not the first time I use split(); on more than two integers, I think it's not about the if statements but something with the reading itself.

Comment: @Eyad: That's what I think so. Sometimes space and enter at the end of the line could be tricky. Try a different separator (ie comma). However, if you enter input in correct format it should work even for the space.

Comment: I do enter input in correct format I am sure I do, I tried using commas instead of spaces it gave me an error on the `nums[i] = convert.ToInt32(input[i]);` line saying "Index was outside the bounds of the array".

Comment: @Eyad: So that error says something is going wrong in Console.ReadLine ().Split (','); Get input to a differnt string and write values to see what you get.
string values = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine(values);

Comment: @Eyad: This is the way to debug an issue. You should narrow down and isolate the issue. If there is no issue with the ReadLine, investigate Split method next...

Comment: @Eyad: Try adding a separator at the end of your input 6,7,445, and see. May be there is something wierd thing happening in Xamarin. I don't know about Xamarin platform...

Comment: @Eyad: Any update on this? Mind to select if there is any appropriate answer for your question.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need a 'break' as you are using if-else if. Below should help

```
if (a > b && a > c) {
    Console.WriteLine (a);
} else if (b > a && b > c) {
    Console.WriteLine (b);
} else {
    Console.WriteLine (c);
}
```

Comment: I tried doing it without a break even before adding the break xD.
edit: this isn't work, obviously

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statements do not handle the numbers with same value

Correct as below:

```
if (a >= b && a >= c) {
    Console.WriteLine (a);
    //break;
} else if (b >= a && b >= c) {
    Console.WriteLine (b);
    //break;
} else {
    Console.WriteLine (c);
    //break;
}
```

Comment: Replaced my if code with this one and still nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input first number: ");
            var a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Input second number: ");
            var b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Input third number: ");
            var c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine(a);
            Console.WriteLine(b);
            Console.WriteLine(c);
            if (a > b && a > c)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(a);
            }
            else if (b > a && b > c)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(b);
            }
            else if (c > a && c > b)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(c);
            }                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Edit:
If you make it dynamic then

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter numbers (Example 25,46,19)");
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (input == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your input is wrong");
                return;
            }
            var numbers = input.Split(',');
            //Sort by descending order
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < numbers.Length - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(numbers[i]) > Convert.ToInt32(numbers[j]))
                    {
                        var temp = Convert.ToInt32(numbers[i]);
                        numbers[i] = numbers[j];
                        numbers[j] = temp.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Greater Number is {0}", numbers[0]);                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I executed your code it works properly if break is removed. there is no loop for the break statement to break and continue.it gives a compilation error. Remove that and it gives the correct result.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgVqB.jpg here is the screen shot

Comment: Try executing it while int c is largest value not b, when it is b it works fine for me, too.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `break;` inside if/else blocks won't let your code compile :) After fixing this, your if/else code block in itself, looks correct. I tested it and it prints out c in my machine.

To answer your question related to ***If statements***, if I were you, I would check:

- If c is really the greatest (it may be greater than a, but not b, then it fails)
- Unwanted space before or after c (maybe failing the conversion? You can try trimming string before conversion.)

This is neater if you can use .Max():

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] input = Console.ReadLine().Split(' '); // getting input as string            
        List<int> nums = new List<int>(); // declaring int array with same length as input
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++) // starting a for loop to convert input string to int in nums[]
        {                
            int intValue;
            if (Int32.TryParse(input[i].Trim(), out intValue))
            {
                nums.Add(intValue);
            }
        }

        int max = nums.Max();
        int min = nums.Min();

        Console.WriteLine("Largest: " + max);
        Console.WriteLine("Smallest: " + min);

        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

This is without .Max():

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] input = Console.ReadLine().Split(' '); // getting input as string            
        List<int> nums = new List<int>(); // declaring int array with same length as input
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++) // starting a for loop to convert input string to int in nums[]
        {                
            int intValue;
            if (Int32.TryParse(input[i].Trim(), out intValue))
            {
                nums.Add(intValue);
            }
        }

        //int max = nums.Max();
        //int min = nums.Min();

        int min = nums[0];
        int max = nums[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (nums[i] < min) min = nums[i];
            if (nums[i] > max) max = nums[i];
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Largest: " + max);
        Console.WriteLine("Smallest: " + min);

        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Note:

- `List<int>` was used to accommodate user adding more than 3 values.
- Avoided using a, b, c so that the program can accept more than 3 values.
- Used `Int32.TryParse(your_string, out outputInt)` to conveniently detect parse errors and move on. Use `.Trim()` to remove spaces before and after each text block.